# Navigate back to CPQ edit lines from VF page triggered by custom action

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, redirect, custom-actions, popup-window

I have a custom action (open in a popup) within the CPQ configurator that triggers the VF page with LWC inside. After some action is performed I want to navigate back to the Edit Line page.
I tried navigating inside the LWC component by using NavigationMixin - not working

```js
var link = '/apex/sbqq__sb?scontrolCaching=1&id=' + this.recordId + '#quote/le?qId=' + this.recordId;
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
 type: 'standard__webPage',
 attributes: {
 url: link
 }
});
```

I also tried doing it inside the VF page, by passing a function to the LWC and on the returned URL doing the redirect.

```js
function navigateToList(url) {
  if (typeof sforce != 'undefined' && sforce && sforce.one) {
   sforce.one.navigateToURL(url);
  } else {
  window.close();
  window.location.href = url;
 }
}
```

The VF page redirect works in a better way, but the configurator is opened in the popup and I can't close it in any way.
I tried firing page reload, but it also reloads the popup page. Also tried with **actionFunction** and the PageReference, but always gets open in a popup.

**UPDATE**
I noticed that it's possible to set the URL of the top.location

```js
window.top.location.href = url;
```

but in that case, the new page has no salesforce headers...